# Paste COUNTIF Formula Results, Not The Formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

Ive been wrestling with this for hours.

I have a script which every 24 hours takes the value from another sheet, and stores it into a cell.  So we can keep a running order...

like

10/4/23 - 10

11/4/23 - 15

12/4/23 - 24

etc etc

Works fine....however, the problem I have is that my script works by pasting the formula, not the results of the formula.  So what I actually end up with is a sheet that constantly updates itself, like....

10/4/23 - 10

11/4/23 - 10

12/4/23 - 10

Does anyone know a method whereby instead of pasting the formula, I can paste the output of the formula? Or even a method to copy the result, and paste it as value only?

My script is here;

```
function addDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  sh.appendRow([d,'=COUNTIF(currentAffiliates!C:C,"Joined")','=COUNTIF(currentAffiliates!C:C,"Rejected")']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the actual values instead of the formulas of `'=COUNTIF(currentAffiliates!C:C,"Joined")','=COUNTIF(currentAffiliates!C:C,"Rejected")'`.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function addDate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  
  // I modiifed the below script.
  var { joined, rejected } = ss.getRange("'currentAffiliates'!C:C").getDisplayValues()
    .reduce((o, [c]) => {
      ["joined", "rejected"].forEach(e => {
        if (e == c.toLowerCase()) {
          o[e]++
        }
      });
      return o;
    }, { joined: 0, rejected: 0 });
  sh.appendRow([d, joined, rejected]);
}
```

- When this script is run, the actual values are appended instead of the formulas of `'=COUNTIF(currentAffiliates!C:C,"Joined")','=COUNTIF(currentAffiliates!C:C,"Rejected")'` to the sheet.
- In this case, I thought that the following modification might be able to be also used.

  - From

    ```
      var { joined, rejected } = ss.getRange("'currentAffiliates'!C:C").getDisplayValues()
        .reduce((o, [c]) => {
          ["joined", "rejected"].forEach(e => {
            if (e == c.toLowerCase()) {
              o[e]++
            }
          });
          return o;
        }, { joined: 0, rejected: 0 });
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var [joined, rejected] = ["joined", "rejected"].map(e => range.createTextFinder(e).matchCase(false).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().length);
    ```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you so much, thats perfect and works exactly as needed.